# Simple batch script does not print variable as intended

Tags: batch-file

What is wrong with this code? it is supposed to print `hello world`

```
@echo off

set message = Hello World
echo %message%
```

I wrote it in notepad, and I saved it as `first.bat`, but when I run it in `cmd.exe`, it tells me `echo is off`

Comment: The recommended way to define a variable is `Set "message=Hello World"`, _(the outer quotes protect the variable and value from leading and trailing spaces, but do not form part of them)_. Your variable is named `message<SPACE>` with a value of `<SPACE>Hello World`. As it stands, unless you modify that line accordingly, you'll need to change the last line to `Echo %message :~1%`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add extra space before the equal sign in the set command.

```
@echo off
set message=Hello World
echo %message%
```

Comment: is the same: ECHO is off.

Comment: @BB: it works fine.

Comment: @BB the only way that would be failing is if you are assigning and attempting to expand a variable within the same parenthesised code block, which in your `minimal reproducable example` you have not shown to be the case. If that is the case, you will need to use delayed expansion and expand your `!variarble!` with exclamaition marks.